# Как создать таблицу при помощи python?

Tags: python, python-docx, fpdf

Есть пример словаря

```
dict = {"IP": ["2.2.2.2", "3.3.3.3"],
        "ports": ["80/http", "443/https"],
        "domains": [{"domain": "example1.com",
                     "web_techn": ['example_webtechn1','example_webtechn2']},
                    {"domain": "example2.com",
                     "web_techn": ['example_webtechn3','example_webtechn4']},
                    {"domain": "example3.com",
                     "web_techn": ['example_webtechn5','example_webtechn6']}],
        "URLs": [ "https://2.2.2.2/ - 200", "http://2.2.2.2/ - 200"],
        "technologys": ['example_techn1','example_techn2']}
```

Как при помощи python на основании словаря возможно создать таблицу 1 в формате pdf или doc?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Таблица 1 - Пример.

Comment: Поясните принцип формирования таблицы почему к примеру `example2.com` относится к `3.3.3.3` а не  `2.2.2.2`

Comment: 3.3.3.3 и 2.2.2.2 относятся ко всем example.com

Comment: Получается в результирующей таблице между `2.2.2.2` и `3.3.3.3` не должно быть разделительной черты?

Comment: По сути нет, но почему то в примере который дали мне они разделены чертой.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот пример кода который создаст подобную таблицу. Используется `fpdf2` и `.multi_cell`:

```py
from fpdf import FPDF, XPos, YPos

datas = [{"IP": ["2.2.2.2", "3.3.3.3"],
        "ports": ["80/http", "443/https"],
        "domains": [{"domain": "example1.com",
                     "web_techn": ['example_webtechn1','example_webtechn2']},
                    {"domain": "example2.com",
                     "web_techn": ['example_webtechn3','example_webtechn4']},
                    {"domain": "example3.com",
                     "web_techn": ['example_webtechn5','example_webtechn6']}],
        "URLs": [ "https://2.2.2.2/ - 200", "http://2.2.2.2/ - 200"],
        "technologys": ['example_techn1','example_techn2']},
        {"IP": ["2.2.2.2", "3.3.3.3"],
        "ports": ["80/http", "443/https"],
        "domains": [{"domain": "example1.com",
                     "web_techn": ['example_webtechn1','example_webtechn2']},
                    {"domain": "example2.com",
                     "web_techn": ['example_webtechn3','example_webtechn4']},
                    {"domain": "example3.com",
                     "web_techn": ['example_webtechn5','example_webtechn6']}],
        "URLs": [ "https://2.2.2.2/ - 200", "http://2.2.2.2/ - 200"],
        "technologys": ['example_techn1','example_techn2']},]

pdf = FPDF() # Создаём новый документ
pdf.add_page() # Добавляем страницу
pdf.set_xy(1, 1) # Удаляем белые границы
pdf.set_font("Times", size=16) # Устанавливаем шрифт

for data in datas:
    line_height = pdf.font_size * 2.5 * (len(data['domains']) * 2) # Находим необходимую высоту строки
    col_width = pdf.epw / 7 # Находим необходимую ширину строки

    # Выводим главную часть таблицы
    pdf.multi_cell(col_width, line_height,'\n'.join(data['IP']),
                border=1, new_y=YPos.TOP, max_line_height=pdf.font_size)
    pdf.multi_cell(col_width, line_height,'\n'.join(data['ports']),
                border=1, new_y=YPos.TOP, max_line_height=pdf.font_size)
    pdf.multi_cell(col_width * 2, line_height,'\n'.join(data['technologys']) + '\n' + '\n'.join(data['URLs']),
                border=1, new_y=YPos.TOP, max_line_height=pdf.font_size)

    # Находим высоту для подразбитых ячеек
    line_height /= len(data['domains'])

    for domain in data['domains']:
        pdf.multi_cell(col_width * 1.5, line_height, domain['domain'],
                    border=1, new_y=YPos.TOP, max_line_height=pdf.font_size)
        pdf.multi_cell(col_width * 2, line_height, '\n'.join(domain['web_techn']),
                    border=1, new_y=YPos.NEXT, new_x=XPos.LEFT, max_line_height=pdf.font_size)
        pdf.set_x(pdf.x - col_width * 1.5) # Перемещяемся назад по x к началу под разбитых ячеек
    
    pdf.set_x(1) # Переходим в начало по оси x

pdf.output('table.pdf')
```

Comment: Да спасибо, не подскажете еще, а что если будет лист таких словарей то что делать?

Comment: @Djapa Исправил ответ для листа словарей.

Comment: Спасибо большое